# Functional style for this multi-task Action

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play framework Action which needs to accomplish 3 things in this order:-

1. get two params (A, B) from request
2. if both params exist then use A to retrieve an entry from cache
3. if entry exists in cache then call a web service with B

What I have so far:-

```
// async since we are calling Async APIs like WS

def myAction = Action.async { implicit request =>

    val A = requestParam(request, "a")   // Option[String]
    val B = requestParam(request, "b")

    val futureResponse = for {

        token <- getFromCache(A) recoverWith {
            case e: Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("Some issue with param or cache", e))
        }
        wsResponse <- webServiceCall(B) recoverWith {
            case e: Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("Some issue with web service call", e))
        }

    } yield Ok(wsResponse.body)

     futureResponse recover {
        case e: Exception => Ok(failureBody(e.getMessage))
    }

}
```

I have obviously left out some details for brevity that are not important to my question.

My question is (as a Scala newbie) what would be a good functional way to complete this Action. If the params do not exist then I would not want to execute the `for` comprehension but return a `Future[Result]` containing an error message. At the moment the only way I can think of doing this is with an `if` test as below but I cannot help suspecting there might be a *purer* way of achieving this.

```
    val A = requestParam(request, "a")   // Option[String]
    val B = requestParam(request, "b")

    if(A.isEmpty || B.isEmpty) {

        Future { Ok("Params missing") }

    } else {

        val futureResponse = for {

            token <- getFromCache(A) recoverWith {
                case e: Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("Some issue with param or cache", e))
            }
            wsResponse <- webServiceCall(B) recoverWith {
                case e: Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("Some issue with web service call", e))
            }

        } yield Ok(wsResponse.body)

        futureResponse recover {
            case e: Exception => Ok(failureBody(e.getMessage))
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any comments as to how people might approach my above solution more elegantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, there are many ways to do things with dependent `Future`s and `Option`s, and it's really a matter of taste. I don't think there's anything inherently wrong in using an `if` expression if it communicates your point more clearly in a given situation. That said you could:

Use a `for` expression with `.getOrElse` to ensure both your parameters are satisfied (though nested `for`s sometimes don't look very nice). A slightly (and needlessly) golfed rewrite of your logic might look like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future.{successful => immediate}

def getFromCache(key: String, data: String): Future[String] = ???
def webServiceCall(key: String): Future[WSResponse] = ???

def myAction = Action.async { implicit request =>
  (for {
    a <- request.getQueryString("a")
    b <- request.getQueryString("b")
  } yield (for {
     cachedData <- getFromCache(a)
     r <- webServiceCall(b, cachedData)
   } yield Ok(r.body)) recover {
      case e => InternalServerError(e.getMessage)
   }) getOrElse {
    immediate(BadRequest("params missing"))
  }
}
```

You've also got the option in Play of using a `Form` to ensure that multiple parameters are present and valid, so you could end up with something like the following (again slightly condensed, expand as necessary):

```
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.data.Form

val form = Form(tuple("a" -> nonEmptyText, "b" -> nonEmptyText))

def myAction2 = Action.async { implicit request =>
  form.bindFromRequest.fold(
    err => immediate(BadRequest("missing params")), { case (a, b) =>
      getFromCache(a).flatMap { cachedData =>
        webServiceCall(b, cachedData).map(r => Ok(r.body))
      } recover {
        case e => InternalServerError(e.getMessage)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

A couple of good posts to read for this kind of thing are:

- [Error Handling in Scala](https://tersesystems.com/2012/12/27/error-handling-in-scala/)
- [How to compose Future and Option in Scala](http://loicdescotte.github.io/posts/scala-compose-option-future/) (possibly a bit much in this context but interesting nonetheless.)

Comment: Mike, many thanks for taking the time to respond in detail. A couple of great options for me to work off. ;)